# Update to PHP 7.x.x

Tags: php

first of all I apologize for my English, I know it's not the best... I found more than one post related to my problem, but unfortunately I do not know PHP code, so I'm not able to resolve my ptroblem...

In my website, I wolud like to update PHP to version 7.x.x, but there is an error:
Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /option-tree/ot-loader.php on line 98

Please, does anybody may hel me to fix this? Below is the line of code that I need to edit.

```
$path = ltrim( end( @explode( get_template(), str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) ), '/' );
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your English actually us exceptionally good, if you only would type a bit slower ;-)

Comment: Please notice that a _Notice_ is not an _Error_...

Comment: Check the PHP docs for your functions: `ltrim()`, `end()`, and `explode()`. Whichever function shows a `&$` in the parameter list is the one causing the notice. @arkascha I think it's good to go after *Notice*s because they can clog up a system with unnecessary logging and can even cause slowdown since it is one more thing which PHP needs to handle; potentially millions of times.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I never said one should ignore a `Notice`! Certainly one should take advantage of the valuable information given there. Not because they "clog up a system", but because there is a reason for them which is always worth exploring.

Comment: Hmm, you are correct, you did not say to ignore them. I guess I just didn't want OP to come to their own conclusion that they are unimportant.

Answer (score 2):

The issue most likely is that you hand over the result of a function call to the `end()` function which expects a *variable*, since it defines a reference as single argument. A function return value may be an array, but not a variable, for obvious reasons. You have to store the result to be able to use it as a reference:

```
$someArray = 
  explode( 
    get_template(), 
    str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) ) 
  ) 
); 
$path = ltrim(end($someArray), '/');
```

Alternatively you could also keep that shorter by using an "inline assignment":

```
$path = ltrim( 
  end(
    $someArray = explode( 
      get_template(), 
      str_replace( '\\', '/', dirname( __FILE__ ) ) 
    ) 
  ), 
  '/' 
);
```

Some personal advice:

- try to keep your expressions more simply. Overly complex language constructs are certainly compact, but extremely hard to read and debug. No one wins that way.
- also you should *never* suppress errors or warnings using the `@` operator before a function identifier. Such warnings offer important information, you should *fix* those issues instead of suppressing them.